# Why rails integration test does not check for proper user right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

In our integration test for rails 3.2.12 app, there is a test case to open the create new user page which only admin has the right to do. Here is our rspec case (with capybara) which passes:

```
it "should have login field in create new user page" do
      ul = FactoryGirl.build(:user_level, :position => 'admin')
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :login => 'test12', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password', :user_levels => [ul])
      visit '/'
      fill_in "login", :with => @user.login
      fill_in "password", :with => 'password'
      click_button 'Login'  
      visit new_user_path
      page.body.should have_content("New User")
end
```

The user position "admin" is defined in user_levels which belongs to a user. What the rspec case above does is to log in and open the create new user page.

In user controller, there is a before_filter to check if the user is admin:

```
before_filter :require_admin
```

The odd thing is that if we assign non-admin position to the user in rspec case above, the case still passes. It seems that the before_filter require_admin fails to stop a non-admin user open the create new user page in integration test.

What could be wrong with the rpsec code above? Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try installing [launchy](http://rubygems.org/gems/launchy) gem and then putting `save_and_open_page` right after `visit new_user_path`? This will show exactly what your test sees before it evaluates page for content "New User".

Comment: yes, we installed launchy. But not sure how to use it. We are not using save_and_open_page. Did you mean we need to put it right after visit_new_user_path?

Comment: Should we remove launchy? We install launchy because some posts says it should go along with capybara. But we have no idea about how to use it.

Comment: No, keep it. just add `save_and_open_page` right after `visit new_user_path`. As soon as `save_and_open_page` is hit, a web browser will open and it will show you what the test sees at this point

Comment: You are right and that's what we have seen. But the test seems stopped. Do we have to manually resume the test again? Or the test will continue to finish by itself.

Comment: Did the page show the new user page even though it's not supposed to be shown for non-admin users? If so, something is wrong with either your `before_filter` or your user levels

Comment: Yes, it is the new user page which is not supposed to be shown. Now we know how to use launchy in this case. Thank you.

Comment: BTW you are right that the before_filter is not working as it is supposed to be.